# Rewrite URL using JS Window.Location without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to rewrite a pages URL without having the page reload it self via Javascript when setting the window.location to slash?

For example, I have an a href item that sets the link to #item1

```
<a href="#item1">
```

and then it's linked up via to a js class that pulls a popup open and when the popups close button is pressed I then rewrite the url to

```
window.location = "/#";
```

Is it possible to rewrite the url to so that there is no hash remaining?

```
window.location = "/";
```

Without having the webpage reload it self since / means home?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the History API.

http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: Oh sweet! This was exactly what I was looking for. Google wasn't yielding results (possibly because I didn't know exactly what to search for), but thanks! I just implemented this and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
var stateObj = { home: "home" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "home", "/");
```